# Javascript. Вызов метода объекта, который находится в массиве.

Tags: javascript

```
var MyObj1 = {
    method: function() {
        //...
    }
};

var MyObj2 = {
    arrayObj: [],
    addObj: function(obj) {
        this.arrayObj.push(obj);
    },
    start: function() {
        try {
            for(var obj in this.arrayObj) {obj.method();}
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e.message); //ошибка. Объект не имеет метода method()
        }
    }
};

MyObj2.addObj(MyObj1);
MyObj2.start();

Спасибо.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

конструкция for a in b возвращает не сами элементы массива/свойства объекта, а их ключи

```
for(var key in this.arrayObj) {this.arrayObj[key].method();}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы вызываете в цикле метод у итератора, а не у объекта. 
Поправьте MyObj2

```
var MyObj2 = {
    arrayObj: [],
    addObj: function(obj) {
        this.arrayObj.push(obj);
    },
    start: function() {
        try {
            for(var i in this.arrayObj) {this.arrayObj[i].method();}
        } catch(e) {
            alert(e.message); //ошибка. Объект не имеет метода method()
        }
    }
};
```